# How to post messages on the same thread using google hangouts chat api webhooks?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, hangouts-api

I am trying to send a post message to the google chat API using webhooks in the same thread when the message is about the same file being processed. Right now the messages are being posted but not in the same thread. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public async Task ExecutionStarted(string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            var today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss");
            string json = "{\"text\":\"" + today + ": Processing file " + fileName + " from " + filePath + "\"}";
            await PostToGoogleChat(json);
        }

public async Task PostToGoogleChat(string json)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(_chatUrl), content);
        }
```

Comment: Hey @MJ9094 were you able to solve your issue? I would love to hear about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to respond to a Thread, you will have to include the thread identifier in the URL of the call. The thread identifier is part of the `parent` parameter (see [`spaces.message.create`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create)).

When you get the message from the webhook (see: [message resource](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages#Message),  you can get the thread it was posted from the `thread` property that it holds). Afterwards, when creating the message you just have to send this exact thread's name (which is its identifier, should look something like `spaces/AAAAMpdlehY/threads/UMxbHmzDlr4`) as the message parent.

Answer (score 1):

According to this docs, just add the threadKey to the query parameter

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages/create

Same threadKey will go to same thread, no need to remember the thread ID from previous post.

Your **request url** will look like
https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAL0vuKXY/messages?key=...&token=...&threadKey=...

Answer (score 1):

Any Post message response will contain in the response payload.

```
"thread": {
    "name": "spaces/AAAASchux4w/threads/GgWXNtFDOpE"
}
```

What you need to do is include this in any future message that one wants to be sent in the same thread.

```
{
    "text": "message in the same thread",
    "thread": {
        "name": "spaces/AAAASchux4w/threads/GgWXNtFDOpE"
     }
}
```

Comment: The damn documentation is so bad, I tried threadKey, thread_key in the query string as documented and only this one worked

Answer (score 0):

When you send the first message you will receive a response json, in this response you receive a `thread` property. Tou have to send new messages with this `thread` property on the same level as text and/or cards.

```
public async Task ExecutionStarted(string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            var today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHH:mm:ss");
            string json = "{\"text\":\"" + today + ": Processing file " + fileName + " from " + filePath + "\"}";
            if(this.currentThread){
                json.thread = this.currentThread
            }
            await PostToGoogleChat(json);
        }

public async Task PostToGoogleChat(string json)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(_chatUrl), content);
            this.currentThread = result.thread
        }
```